# Approximation - Weight function

Tags: approximation

Hi could anyone help with this task (point C):

https://zapodaj.net/a079f713ac6c0.png.html

As far I've got: $$Q(θ) = ∫_0^1(u^2−au_n)^2*(−2u+2)du$$

What next? Derivative by $$u$$ of this calculus function and then equate it to zero?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE!  Please [don't link to external images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/240723/259305) because their URL is *unstable*: they can be replaced by whoever controls the image hosts.  Please use the embed image button to host the image on this site (to i.stack.imgur.com).

Comment: Sorry, but I cant add images right now (I don't have enough reputation)

Comment: Yes you can, please see [meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21341/290189) for a tutorial.  See [an example question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2718913/290189) with image hosted on this site by [a user with less than 10 reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/448192/haziranyagmur).